# Clone a DOM event object to re-dispatch

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Some browsers won't allow you to re-dispatch an event that has already been dispatched, but allow you to create new event objects based on values that can be obtained from the existing event object.

Is there a generic and reusable solution that will work with any event type, or failing that, a way to do this for a specific event type (in my case I'm currently concerned with the `mousewheel` event)?

Comment: did you try `element.dispatchEvent(your mousewheel event)` ? You should be able to instanciate a new mousewheel event I think through `createEvent()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems there is now an even better solution, since `initMouseEvent` and the like are deprecated. The [MouseEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) constructor, for example,  takes a table of properties as its second parameter, for which you can use an existing MouseEvent object:

```
let my_event = new MouseEvent(`foo`, some_existing_mouse_event);
dispatchEvent(my_event);
```

Other classes of events have similar constructors that should be usable in the same way. Such as [ClipboardEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/ClipboardEvent).

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/99yst971/)

Comment: Awesome. This is the best way I've seen. Thank you.

Comment: some properties cannot be copied with this method, target or currentTarget for example.

Comment: @shuji You can set the value after like: `my_event.target = some_element`

Comment: **Note** that there's also `WheelEvent`, for scrolling, and `MouseEvent` won't function properly for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent

Answer (score 5):

I found my own answer, at least for MouseEvents specifically:

```
function cloneMouseEvent( e ) {
    var evt = document.createEvent( "MouseEvent" );
    evt.initMouseEvent( e.type, e.canBubble, e.cancelable, e.view, e.detail, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, e.ctrlKey, e.altKey, e.shiftKey, e.metaKey, e.button, e.relatedTarget );
    return evt;
}
```

You can then dispatch the event on a target with:

```
target.dispatchEvent( evt );
```

Comment: could you share with us the value for 'e', the parameter of cloneMouseEvent ? Of course it will be only the values *you* need, but it still can help to avoid some pitfalls...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, `e` is the JavaScript event object passed to the initial event handler--i.e. the one I want to clone.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the (poorly documented) [NWEvents library](http://javascript.nwbox.com/NWEvents/)

```
NW.Event.dispatch(target, e.type, false, e);
```

Works with any event, and in older IEs too.